# is there any way to cache the webpage in electron for offline support?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to create an electron app where I just use the electron as container and load my webpage using the URL inside it.Just like to know if there is way i can cache the webpage like PWA does and incase of webserver not available I will server it from my cache .As of now when the  app is offline then I just see a white page .Do i have to use something like service worker to serve the webpage .Any clue on this would be helpful .